# Does any continuous map between two Banach spaces over a nonarchimedian field is a closed map?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

Does any continuous map between two Banach spaces is a closed map? It seems to me that it is true. Let $f:V \rightarrow W$ be a map, where $V$, $W$ are (infinite dimensional) Banach space over a a field $K$ which is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then since $V$ is complete which implies that $f(V)$ is complete as $f$ is continuous. Now complete subspace of Hausdorff space is closed. That implies that $f(V)$ is closed. Now take any closed subset $L$ of $V$. Then $L$ is complete and using the same argument $f(L)$ is closed. So $f$ is a closed map. Is my proof correct?

If not the what are the condition in which $f$ can be a closed map?

Comment: If $f$ linear? Also, what role does $\mathbb{Q}_p$ play here?

Comment: You can assume that $f$ is linear. This is a question of nonarchimedean functional analysis. I don`t know whether $\Bbb{Q}_p$ will play any role but I am interested over functional analysis over nonarchimedean fields only

Comment: Why does the completeness of $V$ imply the completeness of $f(V)$? This is not true over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ - are you using something special about $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: @Prahlad. Thaks for pointing out. I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct analog of closed Graph theorem of non-archimedean fields. see page 61, theorem 3.5 in [Non-archimedean functional analysis. A. C. M. van Rooij](http://bookfi.org/book/2229708).